# Avoiding memcpy in C++ buffered output

Tags: c++, linux, fstream, buffered

I am trying to write directly to an fstream output buffer to avoid a `memcpy`.

Why does the following code not work?

It compiles, runs and produces the right length output file on Linux. But the output file does not contain correct text. Also note that for some reason, when I comment out the two lines involving `str2`, then an output file of zero length is produced.

**Note:** This example does not avoid `memcpy`, but if it works, it will help me avoid a `memcpy` in my application.

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::fstream out;
  char buffer[512];
  out.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, 512);
  out.open("file.txt", std::fstream::out);
  char *str1 = "test text.";
  strcpy(buffer, str1);
  out.rdbuf()->pubseekpos(strlen(str1), std::ios_base::out);
  char *str2 = "why?";
  out << str2;
  out.flush();
  out.close();
}
```

Comment: `to avoid a memcpy` -- sorry, but this is just silly. `memcpy` is one of the fastest operations.

Comment: Are you actually sure that the cost of the `memcpy` actually *matters* compared to the cost of the actual I/O being done? Have you profiled it? This may simply be a premature optimization and you should be concentrating your efforts elsewhere.

Comment: There are several comments as to "why" I am doing it. Let's leave out those for the moment. Bottom line is that the code does not produce an output file with text: "test text. why?" Can someone tell me why?

Comment: @Xeo: Not only are you being annoying by answering a question that was not asked, you're also wrong.  While memcpy() is fast, its cost is measurable and eliminating it can yield noticeable performance benefits, like a 10% benefit I measured in a parser I've written: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/77955

Comment: @Josh: "by answering" - I put this as a comment exactly because it's not an answer.

Comment: If you want to access a file via a pointer I'd suggest just using a memory mapped file.

Comment: You're avoiding a `memcpy` but using a `strcpy` (and a `strlen`) ? What kind of sense does that make?

Answer (score 2):

You give the stream a buffer for **its** internal use. Then you don't give it anything to write.

The fact that you copy something to the buffer **without telling the stream** doesn't give you anything in the file.

As you might have noticed, the seekpos is for positioning in the file, not for moving in the buffer. The buffer is for the stream's internal use only!

Answer (score 1):

When you `out.rdbuf()->pubseekpos(strlen(str1), std::ios_base::out);`, this asks the stream to skip forwards through the newly created file.  Can you expect it to take stuff from the buffer you specified?  A clue: have you seen any examples involving specifying a buffer that said you needed to initialise it in some way or specify the initial number of non-garbage characters it contained?  No... because the stream itself tracks which parts of the buffer are in use.  Hence - when you take the presumed empty-buffer and skip forwards, it generates the intervening NULs.  It wouldn't make sense for them to be set in the buffer (so simply doing a `memcpy` after the `pubseekpos` won't work either) - what if you've jumped more than a buffer-size forwards?

Hopefully this serves to at least illustrate the problem, although I haven't given any thought at this stage to how you might force the stream to change it's "tracking" of meaningful buffer content....

Answer (score 0):

It's still early, but aren't you basically doing

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

  std::fstream out;
  out.open("file.txt", std::fstream::out);

  out << "test text";
  out << "why?";

  out.flush();
  out.close();
}
```

?

Comment: In this example, yes! But can I get direct (read pointer) access to the output buffer?

Comment: what do you want to achieve by that? since you do not call any write operation I am pretty sure that some implementation will not write anything. you are manipulating memory but not writing to a file. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: @user No, but I believe you can copy it into the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with the C++ iostream library to say what is wrong with your program, I would only mention that if you want to do your own buffering it would likely be more straightforward to use the read() and write() interfaces directly (man 2 write).  If you're doing your own buffering the iostream libraries probably won't buy you much, and will only obscure what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

I see three possibilities

1. Implement your own stream-buffer class
2. Use the native file API
3. Disable buffering with `pubsetbuf(0, 0)`

Implementing a stream-buffer is really not that difficult, and would give you the opportunity to mix C++ style stream insertion with direct memory access, without 
sacrificing performance.